# Any way to make it so that a single style doesn't affect a certain element?

Tags: css

The situation is this: I have 4 divs of equal size with different content in each one. The CSS for these divs is:

```
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4{
  width: 24%;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(15px);
}
```

So my question is, is it possible to make it so that div3 is the only div not affected by the `text-align` style?

I know it's possible with JavaScript, as that's the solution I already have. What I want to know is if this can be done using ONLY CSS without just overriding the style?

This is more of a question so that I can expand my arsenal, because you can never know too much!

Answer (score 1):

`text-align: initial` or `text-align: unset` will do the trick:

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4{
  width: 24%;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(15px);
  
  background: lightblue;
}

#div3{text-align: initial}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    Text in div
</div>
<div id="div2">
    Text in div
</div>
<div id="div3">
    Text in div
</div>
<div id="div4">
    Text in div
</div>
```

### Update

Method 2:

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4{
  width: 24%;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(15px);
  
  background: lightblue;
}

#div1, #div2, #div4{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    Text in div
</div>
<div id="div2">
    Text in div
</div>
<div id="div3">
    Text in div
</div>
<div id="div4">
    Text in div
</div>
```

Method 3:

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4{
  width: 24%;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(15px);
  
  background: lightblue;
}

.div:not(:nth-child(3)){
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="div">
    Text in div
</div>
<div id="div2" class="div">
    Text in div
</div>
<div id="div3" class="div">
    Text in div
</div>
<div id="div4" class="div">
    Text in div
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured this might be the only other option. I meant more along the lines of a `:not()` kind of thing. Not that it's an issue though, I was more curious than anything!

Comment: Not in the same declaration. You have to set it separately. See examples two and three in my edit for the other two main ways to do this.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks for the clarification!